# Improve couchbase like query performance

Tags: database, nosql, couchbase, sql++

I have a N1QL query which takes 20 seconds to complete. Database contains 1.1 million records and it has a GSI for locationCode, type. Below is the query.

> SELECT * FROM `appdb` WHERE locationCode="1-1-03-010" AND 
>   type="institute" AND lowerName LIKE "%acg%" LILMIT 10 OFFSET 0;

But the performance is very poor. Can you please suggest me on how to improve the performance of the above query? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I assume that's a typo with "LILMIT"?

Answer (score 0):

Check the Plan Text of the query to see which parts of the query plan are taking the longest. If you are using Couchbase 5 Enterprise, you should be able to look at a graphic representation as well.

You may not be hitting the index you expect, or maybe since you are selecting *, it's taking a long time to actually project the data (I don't know how big your documents are). It's really difficult to speculate without those details.

But if I had to speculate, the `LIKE` is most likely what is taking up a lot of time. Is this supposed to be a text-driven search? If so, you may want to consider using Couchbase's [Full Text Search](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/sdk/full-text-search-overview.html) (FTS) feature instead of N1QL for that use case. Create an FTS index on the `lowerName` field (at least).

Comment: @theMayer this isn't really the forum for that discussion, and I don't represent the product management team when I say this but a) you do not need to use N1QL with Couchbase if you don't want to. Key/value, map/reduce, and other methods are still there. b) SQL is a good query language that many developers are comfortable with, and it makes learning Couchbase easier.